# How to create hover/active link similar to this image?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, menu, header

**Guys need your help**
I am creating a menu list with hover and active link similar to the below image.
I need to create a gradient circle below the link.

This is a sample image for better understanding.
[image]

This is my code:

```css
header, ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: cornsilk;
}
ul {
    height: 80px;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0 18px;
}
header a {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #555555;
    text-decoration: none;
}
header a:hover {
    color: #EB6060;
}
.active {
    color: #EB6060;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="active" href="menu1.html">Menu 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 4</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 5</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not clear pic, i guess linear gradient effect is enough .

```css
header, ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: cornsilk;
}
ul {
    height: 80px;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0 18px;
}
header a {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #555555;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
}
header a:hover {
    color: #EB6060;
}
.active {
    color: #EB6060;
}

header a:hover::after,
.active::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 1.4em;
  left: calc(50% - .3em);
  width: .6em;
  height: 0.6em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(230, 100, 101), rgb(145, 152, 229));
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="active" href="menu1.html">Menu 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 4</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 5</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working. But the circle is not coming to the centre of li.

Comment: i update the code. now it's in center .

Comment: It's working fine. Thank you.